# SVG filter only working when added in style attribute (Firefox)

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, svg-filters

I added a blur effect svg to my HTML(text/html):

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        ...
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="0">
            <filter height="116%" width="116%" y="-8%" x="-8%" id="svgBlur">
                 <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8" in="SourceGraphic"/>
            </filter>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which I reference to in my CSS sheet:

```
#page-container {
    filter: url("#svgBlur");
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
}
```

**Doing this makes the #page-container appear white** (FF doesn't recognize the SVG filter).

---

**The funky part:**

When I disable the above filter rule in Firebug and readd it in the style attribute of the #page-container, it works like a charm.

```
<div id="page-container" style="filter: url("#svgBlur");">
```

What am I overseeing?

---

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control   no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Language    nl
Content-Length  6098
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Mon, 02 Dec 2013 14:47:01 GMT
Etag    "1385995621"
Expires Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=100
Last-Modified   Mon, 02 Dec 2013 14:47:01 +0000
Link    </nl/node/215271>; rel="canonical",</nl/node/215271>; rel="shortlink"
Server  Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
Vary    Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.19
```

---

`Problem on Firefox 25 OSX. Webkit browsers work fine, because they use the css blur filter`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I included the svg as a base64 string directly into the css file.
This solved my problem.

```
filter:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBoZWlnaHQ9IjAiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PGZpbHRlciBpZD0ic3ZnQmx1ciI+PGZlR2F1c3NpYW5CbHVyIGluPSJTb3VyY2VHcmFwaGljIiBzdGREZXZpYXRpb249IjgiLz48L2ZpbHRlcj48L3N2Zz4=#svgBlur)
```

Comment: Works nicely in Firefox but does not work in Chrome due to [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109212). Note that a data uri is an external reference in this context. Probably also exists in all webkit browsers as there is a webkit bug referenced there also.

Comment: Note that inline SVG in `filter` may fail if you use `Content-Security-Policy` (CSP) because the expected behavior is poorly specified. For details, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=878608 –  the bad part is that if this happens with Firefox the element with `filter` will immediately turn 100% transparent instead of filter not being effective!

Answer (score 20):

`#svgBlur` is a relative URL. It is converted to an absolute URL by prepending the name of the file it is in so

```
filter: url("#svgBlur");
```

in your case is really just a shorthand for

```
filter: url("stylesheet.css#svgBlur");
```

Which doesn't point to anything.

You need to put the name of the html file in the URL

```
filter: url("yourhtmlfile.html#svgBlur");
```

will work. And that's why it works when it's in the html file of course as the prepended filename points to the right place in that case.

Comment: See the comment of Josh Powell. I'm referring to a svg filter which is included in my HTML. And which should work fine

Comment: My HTML roughly looks something like this:

    <html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
    ...
    <svg>...</svg>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: The styles are defined in a seperate css file which is included by a <link rel=... /> The svg and the #page-container are in the same file

Comment: To be clear, if the line `filter: url("#svgBlur");` is not in the same file as the svg element then you'll need to prepend the filename of the svg/HTML file to the URL. Is that the case?

Comment: A perfect answer - this has been driving me nuts for hours!

Comment: +1 - Also if it helps anyone, `filter: url(".#svgBlur");` worked for me in firefox.

Answer (score 2):

My problem that led me here was I had hidden the SVG inside of a div with "display: none" embedded in the class.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine in firefox like so,

**HTML**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="0">
   <filter height="116%" width="116%" y="-8%" x="-8%" id="svgBlur">
       <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8" in="SourceGraphic"/>
   </filter>
</svg>
<div id="page-container">
   <img src="http://miriadna.com/desctopwalls/images/max/Fairy-forest.jpg" alt="forest" />
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/77HLj/) (with an image in the div)

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/77HLj/1/) (with a background image on the div)

Did you included the the `svg` code in your html markup?

Comment: Yes i included it just before the end of my body.
I added my code to another test page, where it worked perfectly fine.

But I can't figure out what influences this behaviour...

PS: I also tried to disable all JS. Didn't work

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if the placement would make a difference but it is very bizarre that it is working in the fiddle. Can you show how the html looks on your page with the `svg` included?

Comment: I added the response headers to the original issue as well

Comment: I looked through your `html` and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it.

Comment: I tried the exact same HTML somewhere else and it works perfectly ... But I cant figure out the external factor here

Answer (score 1):

In my case Firefox didn't find an SVG filter because of the CSS rule:

```
#svg-filters {
    display: none;
}
```

where `svg-filters` is the id of the `<svg>` tag containing all filters definitions. Replaced those lines with

```
#svg-filters {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

and filters work fine in FF.

Referencing filters relative to the HTML document from CSS works fine in major browsers, as pointed out by Josh Powell in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20330458).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the ways to solve this problem without making inline-filter (with base64 string in css) from this thread, including using full path to .svg file in url(), but the only one method solved this problem for me. Firefox see the filter only if you applying css rule in style attribute of element, or if you define css  rules in inline `<style></style>` tag.

Answer (score -3):

What zelanix said above... about adding a . before the filter as in

```
.blur1 {
filter:url(.#blur1);
}
```

Does the trick 100% and works in all browsers from what I can tell