# SVG with Shadow not displaying on some pages in Firefox

Tags: html, svg, svg-filters

So here's the svg script (I have it embedded like this on the page):

```
<svg id="cartTab" viewBox="0 0 600 65" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
        <defs>
            <filter id="tabShadow" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="110%" height="110%">
                <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="0" />
                <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="2" />
                <feComponentTransfer>
                    <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.3"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feMerge> 
                    <feMergeNode/>
                    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
                </feMerge>
            </filter>            
        </defs>
        <path fill="#658FBF" d="M4,65.7V16.4C4,9.7,9.7,4,16.4,4c0,0,234.6,0,276.8,0c136,0,113.6,61.7,272.1,61.7
        C625.1,65.7,4,65.7,4,65.7z" filter="url(#tabShadow)"/>        
        </svg>
```

Now this displays in Chrome and IE on all pages just fine, however in firefox, I can only get this to display on my homepage, all the other pages it's just not there.  If I remove the shadow filter it works though.

Am I doing something wrong with the filter?

Comment: Sounds like you're using a `<base>` html attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Ah found the answer here:
[SVG filter only working when added in style attribute (Firefox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330149/svg-filter-only-working-when-added-in-style-attribute-firefox)

I just had to prepend the current page before the #tabShadow.

So now the filter is:

```
filter="url([CURRENT URL]#tabShadow)"
```

So an example would be:

```
filter="url(about#tabShadow)"
```