# CSS bevel filter in Firefox with Laravel 5.4 project

Tags: css, firefox, svg, laravel-5.4

what is the correct syntax in css for a firefox bevel filter to resolve correctly in a `Laravel` project? I [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330149/svg-filter-only-working-when-added-in-style-attribute-firefox) the reason for the problem and also a suggested solution.

I have tried:

```
filter: url(#bevel);             <-- resolves the image but no bevel filter
filter: url(../index#bevel);     <-- resolves the image but no bevel filter
filter: url(index.php#bevel);    <-- resolves the image but no bevel filter
filter: url(index.html#bevel);   <-- does not show image at all
```

My `bevel` filter in the inline SVG:

```
        <filter id="bevel" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="150%" height="150%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="0.5" result="blur"/>
            <feSpecularLighting in="blur" surfaceScale="5" specularConstant="0.5" specularExponent="10" result="specOut" lighting-color="white">
                <fePointLight x="-5000" y="-5000" z="8000"/>
            </feSpecularLighting>
            <feComposite in="specOut" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="specOut2"/>
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut2" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="litPaint" />
        </filter>
```

This is what Firefox says in its `inspect`

```
#map-user-online-svg, #map-user-offline-svg {
    -webkit-filter: url(../big-risk#bevel);
    filter: url(../big-risk#bevel);      <-- could not load the image
    fill: white;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could simply answer the questions I asked in my comment on your previous identical question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778032/svg-filter-for-firefox-in-laravel-environment

Comment: I thought I did. I additionally decided to ask in a different / simpler way.

Comment: As before: Can you create a [mcve] that has the code post laravel processing i.e. what the browser sees?

Comment: Are you using a web server here, or are you using the file protocol to load the page?

Comment: Hi Robert, it is Homestead and Laravel. All local and in a VM. Using Blade templates

Comment: You can't refer to things outside your current directory or it's children locally on Firefox (on Chrome it's current directory only). So the ../ may be your problem.